# Error: Deck::Deck names the constructor not the type

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I'm trying to overload the ++ and -- operators with the following code:

```
Deck::Deck& operator--(); 
{
    pop();
    Deck *this;
}      
Deck::Deck operator--(int q);
{
    pop();
    Deck *this;
}
Deck::Deck& operator++(); 
{
    push();
    return *this;
}      
Deck::Deck operator++(int q);
{
    push();
    return *this;
}
```

This results in an error saying that Deck::Deck names the constructor not the type. My question is if I'm implementing this code wrong. This is in a deck.cpp file whereas in deck.h is where the prototypes are along with the deck class itself. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: change `Deck::Deck` to `Deck` in return type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the error by the compiler `Deck::Deck` is the constructor of class `Deck` so can't be used as a return type, instead, if you want to return an object of type `Deck` then change the return type to `Deck`.

Also if the functions are member functions of class `Deck` then the definition should be like this for defining outside the class:

```
Deck Deck::operator--() { // or Deck Deck::operator--(int)
     ^^^^^^
    // body
}
```

Comment: When I try that i get this error: "Deck operator--(int) must have an argument of class or enumerated type"

Comment: If i replace Deck::Deck with just Deck in any of the lines then I get that error for each of the lines

Comment: are these  member functions??